# Find and modify, fetch the data, process it and save- Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid in my Rails application and found i can use `find_and_modify` command to update a document as soon as find operation succeeds.

consider a collection `User` below document structure

- name
- points

so the documents are saved like

```
{ "_id" : "51a7420eb09de918204883c4", "name" : "balan", "points" : 1727 }
```

now how do i update the points count as soon as i fetch the record, is there any way to do like below

```
User.where(id: "51a7420eb09de918204883c4").find_and_modify( "$set" => { points: points + 1 } )
```

i.e., the system should fetch the stored points and increment it by 1 and save it back again.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try using $inc for this. There is an example of using $inc for an update on this page: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

Comment: you don't need find_and_modify for this.  An update would do what you want (find document, update it).  find_and_modify is when you need the document then returned to you atomically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the link James.

Got the solution

```
User.where(id: "51a7420eb09de918204883c4").find_and_modify({ "$inc" => { points: 1  } })
```

as per mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html –  James Wahlin in comments.

Comment: slight typo.  change from $inr to $inc

Answer (score 0):

As James said, increment is the way to go:

```
User.where(id: "51a7420eb09de918204883c4").inc(:points, 100)
```

This will find all records with the given ID (or whatever you query), increment the value of points by 100, and save it again. Pretty nifty. You can call it on any mongoid query or individual record too, so `User.find("some-id").inc(:points, 100)` and `User.first.inc(:points, 100)` will work as well.